# How to simplify the my query and use additional commands?

Tags: c#, postgresql

How to simplify the my query and use additional commands? I turn to the three tables in turn. It seems difficult. I ask help.

```
result = "<p>" + (++num) + ")" + node.Text + "</p>";
foreach (var itm in _dbContext.ERIPKEY.Where(k => k.PKeyName == node.Text).ToArray())
{
    foreach (var itmk in _dbContext.ERIKEY.Where(s => s.PKey == itm.PKey).ToArray())
    {
        foreach (var item in _dbContext.ERIPKEYMOUNTING.Where(t => t.MIndex == itmk.MIndex).ToArray())
        {
            result += "<p> - " + item.Note + "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI all the `ToArray()` calls can be eliminated.  A `foreach` loop operates on something that implements `IEnumerable`, so you can exclude the materialization logic (e.g the `ToArray()` calls) and just iterate over the results of the `Where()`

Comment: Use Linq join instead of nested loops.

Comment: My code works, but I'm learning and I'd like to correct my mistakes. In my opinion, I wrote badly. I want to see the best option

Comment: How it can be rewritten on Linq

Comment: Are you trying to create HTML using string concatenation? Save yourself days of frustration by using [`HtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.htmlstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq join solution in LinqPad. I use Northwind database and join 4 tables: `Customers`, `Orders`, `OrderDetails` and `Products`. I'm using SQL Server Express, so I assume you have proper Linq driver for PostgreSQL.

```
var _dbContext = new UserQuery(Connection); // LinqPad only, change to your dbcontext constructor
var query =
    from customer in _dbContext.Customers
    join order in _dbContext.Orders on customer.CustomerID equals order.CustomerID
    join orderDetail in _dbContext.OrderDetails on order.OrderID equals orderDetail.OrderID
    join product in _dbContext.Products on orderDetail.ProductID equals product.ProductID
    where customer.ContactName == "Peter Franken"
    select new
    {
        CustomerName = customer.ContactName,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        ProductName = product.ProductName,
        Subtotal = orderDetail.UnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity
    };

foreach(var q in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", q.CustomerName, q.OrderDate, q.ProductName, q.Subtotal);
```

**Result in LinqPad**

[image]

Generated SQL command from that query in LinqPad:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Peter Franken'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ContactName] AS [CustomerName], [t1].[OrderDate], [t3].[ProductName], [t2].[UnitPrice] * (CONVERT(Decimal(29,4),[t2].[Quantity])) AS [Subtotal]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CustomerID] = [t1].[CustomerID]
INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS [t2] ON [t1].[OrderID] = [t2].[OrderID]
INNER JOIN [Products] AS [t3] ON [t2].[ProductID] = [t3].[ProductID]
WHERE [t0].[ContactName] = @p0
```

Last, you might want to use `StringBuilder` to concatenate the strings if the result of the query is large.